# how can i pass a value from the input into the sum method

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have tried to add it directly to the method but its not working

i think i have a problem with the concatination am new in coding can someone please assist

```
$status=$request->input('status');

$position = DB::table('ratings')
                ->select('user_id', DB::raw('SUM($status) as points'))
                ->groupBy('user_id')
                ->get();
```

any help i will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use `select()` when using the aggregate method as `sum`:

```
$position = DB::table('ratings')
               ->groupBy('user_id')
               ->sum($status);
```

Though, I do not know what is in your $status variable so it may work or not depending on what's in it.

Comment: thank you. i have a rating table with multiple columns(Opening,verification,probing,understanding) i want to pass this column value as an input into the method do the sum and return the results grouped by the user_id eg. user_id 2 points 23 user_3 points 56 user_4 points 56

Comment: $status=$request->input('status');
      $ranks = Rating::query()->with('user')
          ->select('user_id')->selectRaw('SUM('.$status.') TotalPoints')
          ->groupBy('user_id')
          ->orderByDesc('TotalPoints')
          ->get();

return new RatingResource($ranks); this has finally worked after hope its safe